# Wordpress Bottom-Fixed Navigation Bar in Divi Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to position the main navigation of my website below an image component using the Divi theme, using position: fixed and bottom: 0px but to no avail. What am I doing wrong and how would I go about this? Should I keep the height of the image component using percentages? because every time I try doing that, the class containing that div overrides it. This is the sort of look I'm going for:

[image: Trying to make it look like this]

[Here](http://www.abaa.co/home) is the page I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Number of changes needed.

First, remove the inline `style="top:0px"` for the `#main-header` element.

Next, remove `top:0` and change to `bottom:0` in

```
#main-header {
  line-height: 23px;
  font-weight: 500;
  /*top: 0;*/
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 43px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Finally, for `#page-container`, change `padding-top: 78px` to `padding-top: 0px`

Answer (score 0):

In you `header.php`, remove the `top: 0`

**HTML**

```
<header class="et_nav_text_color_dark" id="main-header" style="top:0"></header>
```

to this:

```
<header class="et_nav_text_color_dark" id="main-header"></header>
```

**CSS**

In your CSS remove `top: 0` from `#main-header` and add the below property

```
#main-header {
  bottom: 0;
}

.et_fixed_nav #page-container {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Followed your instructions to the letter, but it just ended up making the whole page, blank with some sort of overlay.